# Domain for telnet service

Tags: domain, telnet

I have a domain, I have working telnet service:

```
telnet x.x.x.x 5555
```

I want to connect it to my domain, i.e.

```
telnet example.com 5555
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Point your domain name ("example.com") to your IP address (x.x.x.x) as an "A" record in your DNS server. I assume you have access to a DNS editor from the place you bought your domain from. This works with any protocol, not just Telnet. I hope you are aware that opening up Telnet to the internet is a dangerous thing to do.

Comment: I've already had two records, but it still not working:

A *                     IP,
A example.com ip

Comment: what happens when you type `nslookup example.com` (for Windows environments) or `dig example.com` (for unix/linux environments). Do you get the IP address you expect?

Comment: it shows cloudflare IP addresses that I put for my domain

Comment: Did you open the port you're trying to reach in your firewall/filter? (Again: *I do not recommend opening up a Telnet port to the internet!*)

Comment: If you get CloudFlare IP addresses, then your domain is working but CloudFlare is not proxying telnet traffic unless you are using Spectrum and have configured it to do so.

Comment: By default, CloudFlare only handles web traffic. You can disable it and set CloudFlare to "DNS only" but you'll lose their CDN and firewall.

Comment: I think it's connected to Cloudflare. Now trying to use 'Delegating Subdomains Outside of Cloudflare'